# How to increase size of filter input in Logcat tab of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, logcat

Android Studio logcat tab filter input has been minimised. Please tell me how to resize it?

[image: See screenshot for more details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the device you use to test has a very long name, by restart android studio normally it will return to its normal size.